# What style has been applied to a QGIS layer?

Tags: qgis, layers, style

QGIS 3.4 - I have several different saved styles which I can assign to a particular layer depending on what I wish to emphasise at the time.
For example, for a Roads layer I might want to show roads in a bold red in one case, but as a faint black line in another. 
Without using Python (this was discussed in an earlier question), where can I simply find the name of the saved style (the .qml file) that has been currently applied to the layer?